# How to draw System.Drawing.Icon to a SplitterPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, graphics, icons

I've got something like this:

```
var systemIcon = SystemIcons.Information;
verticalSplitPanel.SplitterDistance = systemIcon.Width;

var g = verticalSplitPanel.Panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawIcon(systemIcon, 0, 0);
```

This compiles and runs without error, but for some reason the icon isn't visible.

I also tried this:

```
var systemIcon = SystemIcons.Information;
verticalSplitPanel.SplitterDistance = systemIcon.Width;

var g = verticalSplitPanel.Panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(systemIcon.ToBitmap(), 0, 0);
```

Again it compiles and runs without error, but doesn't show the icon.

How can I display this icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can paint icon over panel's surface, but it will be cleared whenever panel decides to repaint itself. Instead of using `Graphics` object from `verticalSplitPanel.Panel1.CreateGraphics()` call you should handle panel's `Paint` event and use `Graphics` object provided in that event args.

Try this:

```
verticalSplitPanel.Panel1.Paint += (s, eargs) =>
    {
        var icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        eargs.Graphics.DrawIcon(icon, 0, 0);
    };
```